# yum install says "Nothing to do" for xorg-x11-libs

Tags: air, x11, yum, rhel, xorg

I'm trying to get AIR2 (ver 2.6) working in RHEL 6.9.

After some research it turned out that the app (air/adl) is 32bit and am on a machine which understands x86_64 instruction set. Ideally it should work, but again as per most forums, the missing "libraries" should be added so that the 32bit app works. Below was the command tried out.

```
sudo yum install xorg-X11-libs.i386
```

But it erred out with below message

```
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
No package xorg-X11-libs.i386 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

As per the '**yum**' configuration file at **/etc/yum.conf**, the value of repos directory is this ***reposdir=/etc/yum.repos.d***

This directory contains two .repo files.

Can you please tell me how can I get the '*xorg-X11-libs.i386*' installed in my machine.

Comment: Why do you need 32-bit libraries for `xorg-x11`, does `yum` asks for them ? What's your repo and commands to install `AIR2` ?

Comment: How about `yum search xorg-X11-libs`?

Comment: @iamauser AIR 2 (to be specific AIR 2.6) was downloaded as a compressed file (tbz); upon unzipping one can see \bin\adl and \bin\adt binaries within them. To run \bin\adl (from terminal), one needs X Forwarding to be enabled (I'm connecting via putty to the Linux machine). The 'adl' is a 32 bit application, and the OS understands x86_64 bit instruction set only. Due to this, I'm unable to bring up the application

Comment: Give us some links to AIR file that you downloaded !

Comment: @n.m. No luck; the same error message is shown "Warning: No matches found for: xorg-X11-libs"

Comment: Try http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=xorg-x11-libs&srodzaj=3